# MySQL startup ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file

Tags: mysql, macos, installation

I'm trying to start mysql in a Mac using `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server` start. I keep getting the following error - `ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/My-MacBook-Pro.local.pid)`. How do I solve this?

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling mysql using home-brew. I have also tried `sudo chown _mysql /usr/local/var/mysql/*` and other things mentioned in other answers.

```
My-MacBook-Pro:~ myusername$ sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
... ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/My-MacBook-Pro.local.pid).
```

Answer (score 1):

A maybe silly answer but it works for me: Try restart your computer.

I met the same problem and I tried every solution I found online. None of them works. I restarted my computer then I can start mysql server successfully...I know lots of mac users don't shut down their computer for a long time.So try restart. Hope it works for you too.